# Powershell [Ref] Value not updating main object

Tags: powershell, pass-by-reference

I'm running Powershell V2 on XP:
This is part of a larger script and I'm noticing some anomolies with the way I'm able to use reference objects to update the "master" object. This started off as a way to avoid typing out the complicated name of the property each time - I could easily expand out to the full name but now the reason for this behaviour is seriously bugging me.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
Function Breakhere {Write-Verbose " "}
Set-PSBreakpoint -Command Breakhere
$Data = @"
UserID
MyUser1
MyUser2
User3
"@
$Data = $Data|ConvertFrom-Csv

$Domains = "DomainA","DomainB"

$Props = "ParentContainer","AccountIsDisabled","employeeNumber"
$Connection = New-Object HashTable

ForEach ($Domain in $Domains)
{
    Write-Verbose "Current Domain: $Domain"
    # Add necessary headers to main data
    $text1 = "$($Domain)_ADObject"
    $text2 = "$($Domain)_Confidence"
    $Data = $Data |Select *,$text1
    $Data = $Data |Select *,$text2

    #Bind to each domain and save the connection contexts into a hashtable
    Write-Verbose "Binding to $Domain"
    $Connection.Add($Domain,(Connect-QADService -service $Domain))
}

ForEach ($User in $Data)
{
    ForEach ($Domain in $Domains)
    {
        $User."$($Domain)_ADObject" = Get-QADUser -Connection $Connection[$Domain] -SamAccountName $User.UserID -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties -IncludedProperties $Props|Select $Props

        # Referencing the confidence parameter does not seem to work.
        $CF = [ref]$User."$($Domain)_Confidence"
        # Weirdly, this one does work.
        $AD = [ref]$User."$($Domain)_ADObject"

        If ($AD.Value)
        {
            $CF.Value = 1 
            Breakhere # Break here and allow for opportunity to inspect $user and $CF objects

            If ($AD.Value.AccountIsDisabled)
            {
                Write-Verbose "$Domain\$($User.UserID): Account Disabled"
                $CF.Value *= 0.8
            }
        }
        Else
        { 
            Write-Verbose "$Domain\$($User.UserID): No AD Object found"
            $CF.Value = 0
        }
    }
} #End ForEach $UserID
```

At the breakpoint, if I query $User, I receive something similar to the following:

```
UserID             : MyUser1
DomainA_ADObject   : @{ParentContainer=DomainA/Users; AccountIsDisabled=False; employeeNumber=123456}
DomainA_Confidence : 
DomainB_ADObject   : 
DomainB_Confidence :
```

All good. Should I wish, I can even use the $AD ref object and update DomainA_ADobject:

```
$AD.Value.employeeNumber = 9999
$User

UserID             : MyUser1
DomainA_ADObject   : @{ParentContainer=DomainA/Users; AccountIsDisabled=False; employeeNumber=9999}
DomainA_Confidence : 
DomainB_ADObject   : 
DomainB_Confidence :
```

However, try this with the $CF ref and the same thing doesn't happen

```
$CF.Value = 2
$CF

Value
-----
2

$User

UserID             : MyUser1
DomainA_ADObject   : @{ParentContainer=DomainA/Users; AccountIsDisabled=False; employeeNumber=9999}
DomainA_Confidence :                         *<====== Expecting this to update!*
DomainB_ADObject   : 
DomainB_Confidence :
```

Why the difference? Is there any way to query a [ref] object and see what it's pointing to? I can't see why one of these is working and the other isn't. They both seem to be set up in the same way. Tried this in ISE and console, same behaviour in both.

Comment: I'm experiencing something similar and can't seem to find an explanation

Comment: `[ref]` should not work here. It is for calling methods with `ref` parameters not for referencing properties.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, that this is caused by dots in the name of domains.
Reducing this to basics $CF.Value = 1 does someting like

$Data[0].domain.name.net.au_Confidence.value = 1

This will not work. This will:

$Data[0]."domain.name.net.au_Confidence".value = 1

Perhaps this will fix it?:

```
$CF = [ref]$User."`"$($Domain)_Confidence`""
```